# PhoneGap: can't display custom error message in Android jQuery app that uses Google Mpas

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova

I've developed an Android app with `jQuery` that uses `Google Maps` with `PhoneGap version 1.4.1`. I want to display a custom error pop-up message when there's no Internet connection:

```
Error: Please check your Internet connection
```

and used the code based of the example as shown in the documentation here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

However, the app only returns the standard `Application Error: Couldn't find URL` message followed by the Google Maps URL. What's the correct way of doing this so I can replace this standard error/exception messages with my own?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

**UPDATE**

If data connection is available but Google Maps is down, an application error pop-up window will appear. But I want to be able to just press OK to acknowledge this error pop-up and still keep using the app. How do I do this?

Here's the code; it's very similar to the demo code in the document. However, it seems like the app already crashed before it even get to this code. So where can this be placed so connection error is caught? This is the first time I'm using jQuery with PhoneGap so I'm not sure how to get these two thing working well together.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load
// 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection();
}

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    if (states[networkState].equals("No network connection") || states[networkState].equals("Unknown connection") || states[networkState].equals("undefined"))
    {
        alert('Type de connection : ' + states[networkState]);
        //navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: show your current code.

Comment: @EmilAdz post updated to include code and additional information